# Install Wine on Ubuntu 13.04 running from a Live USB?

Tags: installation, 13.04, wine, live-usb

I tried to install Wine on my Ubuntu 13.04 setup (running from a live USB). I desperately need Wine installed as quickly as possible as my laptop has a MBR problem that I have to fix and the only way I can see that I can fix it is using a tool which only runs on Windows. I also have some issues with installing Ubuntu 13.04 from my USB (I think it is a problem with the hard drive or something). So my main question is can one install Wine on Ubuntu as a live session from a USB? I get the following errors when trying to install Wine from the Ubuntu Software Centre.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
wine1.4: PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.15.7.2~) but 1.16.10ubuntu1 is to be installed
     Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.17-0ubuntu5 is to be installed
     Depends: wine1.4-amd64 (= 1.4.1-0ubuntu5) but 1.4.1-0ubuntu5 is to be installed
     Depends: wine1.4-i386 (= 1.4.1-0ubuntu5) but it is not going to be installed
```

Thank you for any responses.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Try to do the same in a Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS Live USB. But I don't recommend you to use a MBR repair tool for Windows in Wine in a Live USB (personally). There will be a solution for your problem with GNU/Linux tools.

Comment: First of all thanks for the response! I have not found the problem with the MBR though so it looks like it will be my only choice as I have looked through multiple tutorials that help restore the MBR but all have failed so far. Work friends of mine suggest that I use the program EasyBCD to try fix the entries and I think I will at least try that. What would be the difference with Ubuntu 12.04.2 Live USB and 13.04 Live USB and also what reasons should I not use EasyBCD via Wine? Thank you in advance for the reply.

Comment: Well, Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS is the second version of Ubuntu 12.04, which is more tested and more stable than 13.04. And I don't recommend you to use the program EasyBCD in Wine over a Live USB because Wine is not suposed to manage the ext4 format as a NTFS, then, what I think is going to happen is to "repair" a simulated C:/ disk drive inside .wine folder. That's why I think that you need a tool for GNU/Linux or a Windows Boot Repair Disk (if you are doing all of this to repair the Windows boot sequence).

Comment: I can handle the change from 13.04 back to 12.04.2, I was just after the faster experience with slightly more features, eh, functionality wins over aesthetical features in this round. I will take your advice and try more to find a GNU/Linux MBR repair tool. Thank you for your feedback @Leopoldo Pla! This was a great way to be introduced to a new forum! This is already much much friendlier than forums like the CBoard :)

Comment: I'll post my comments as an answer, as them helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Try to do the same in a Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS Live USB. But I don't recommend you to use a MBR repair tool for Windows in Wine in a Live USB (personally). There will be a solution for your problem with GNU/Linux tools.

I recommend you Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS because is the second version of Ubuntu 12.04, which is more tested and more stable than 13.04. And I don't recommend you to use the program EasyBCD in Wine over a Live USB because Wine is not suposed to manage the ext4 format as a NTFS, then, what I think is going to happen is to "repair" a simulated C:/ disk drive inside .wine folder. That's why I think that you need a tool for GNU/Linux or a Windows Boot Repair Disk (if you are doing all of this to repair the Windows boot sequence).